# How to get fifth highest salary from salary table by single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can get second highest salary by this query. is it possible to use this query for calculate fifth highest salary??

```
SELECT max(salary) 
FROM [Employee] 
where (EmployeeID not in 
  (SELECT max(EmployeeID ) FROM [Employee] ))
```

please help me...

Comment: Your query appears unrelated to salaries.

Comment: This is not a MySQL query.  It looks like MS Access or SQL Server.

Comment: But there is solution for this question i am finding that. if it is possible to use this query.